# Excel VBA: Excel range to just opened powerpoint

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

I have already the code to open a specific powerpoint template from a sharepoint. It already works. What I want next is to copy multiple ranges from different sheets to the first slide of the template of the newly opened powerpoint.  By the way, my sheets are 4 and each has defined ranges to copy. I would like it to paste on the same slide with different positions.

Currently I only have this code to open the powerpoint template:

```
Sub SPPPT()

'*************Open template in sharepoint*****************************

Dim FullTemplatePath As String
Set PPApp = New PowerPoint.Application
Dim OperationalKPI As Worksheet
Set OperationalKPI = Sheets("OperationalKPI")
Dim mySlide As Object
Dim myShape As Object
Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Dim myPresentation As Object

FullTemplatePath = "FilePathofPowerpointTemplate/PPT Template.pptx"

'Open the PowerPoint template
PPApp.Presentations.Open (FullTemplatePath)

Dim OperationalKPI As Worksheet
Set OperationalKPI = Sheets("OperationalKPI")

Set rng = OperationalKPI.Range("KPIRange")


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can paste the data in various formats.  There is a good article [here](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/3/17/copy-paste-an-excel-range-into-powerpoint-with-vba) on how to do this, in particular the bit about the different file formats that you can paste the data via.

The method pastes it as a `shape`. Here is some code I use that is similar to the article:

```
'//Create and open powerpoint
Dim ppt As PowerPoint.Application
Set ppt = New PowerPoint.Application

'//Set objects and open powerpoint
Dim oPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim oTargetSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim oSelect As PowerPoint.ShapeRange

Set oPresentation = ppt.Presentations.Open(sFileName)

'//Copy the data
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B4:B8").Select
Selection.Copy

'//Paste it into powerpoint
With ppt
    Set oTargetSlide = oPresentation.Slides(1)
    oTargetSlide.Select
    ppt.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide oTargetSlide.SlideIndex
    Set oSelect = 
    oTargetSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject)
    '//You can now change the .Left, .Top etc of oShape to place it where you want it.
End With

'//Get the save file name....
'... your code here
oPresentation.SaveAs (SaveAsName)
oPresentation.Close
ppt.Quit
```

I either paste as a ppPasteEnhancedMetafile, ppPastePNG or ppPasteOLEObject.

One key difference with what I am doing is that I am using the PowerPoint 16 object library, rather than just declaring my PowerPoint "as Object".